# Can you make a button create itself?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, tkinter-canvas

So I want to make a button, that when I click on it, it gets deleted and another one appears, and this can be done an infinite amount of times

```
a=0
button1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def ButtonClick():

     global a
     #Destroys the first button
     button1[a].destroy()

     a+a+1

     #Making new button, that should do the same as the old button
     button1[a] = tk.Button(text='hello',command=ButtonClick)
     canvas1.create_window(250+a*50, 140, window=button1[a])


  

button1[a] = tk.Button(text='hello',command=ButtonClick)
canvas1.create_window(100, 140, window=button1[a])
```

As you can see the new button is also using **command=ButtonClick** so when I press on the created button it should do the same as the old one, but it doesn't and I am not sure why because when I change the command on the new button it says error so it is somehow refereeing to the **def ButtonClick**. But nothing happens when I press the new button. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Assign a real name and `append()` it to the list if you want to keep reference.

Comment: Why would you want to delete and recreate a button rather than just reuse it? You can alter all of the properties of a button. It doesn't seem to make much sense to destroy a button and recreate a button rather than just reuse it.

Comment: You know that you did `a+a+1`. I think you wanted `a = a+1`. If that is the case `a += 1` is better

Answer (score 0):

In order to destroy and rebuild a button, you will have to make it global. Here is a working example of a button that can be destroyed by its own function, only to be created again:

```
def ButtonClick():
    global root
    root.b.destroy()
    root.b = Button(root,text="Hello",command=ButtonClick)
    root.c.create_window(250+root.button1[root.bnumber]*50,140,window=root.b)
    if root.bnumber<len(root.button1)-1:root.bnumber+=1
    
global root
root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.c = Canvas(root,bg="#ffffff",width=800,height=600)
root.c.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W+S+E+N)

root.b = Button(root,text="Hello",command=ButtonClick)
root.c.create_window(100,140,window=root.b)
root.button1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
root.bnumber = 0
```

I made your button1 list and the current index (a) attributes of the tkinter widget, so it will be accessible as long as a function has access to the widget.

For this example, however, it would be easier to just move the window within the tkinter Canvas instead of removing and re-creating it.